# Help fix my tablet?

Tags: google-play-store

My Next book tablet isn't working. The Google Play Store keeps saying check connection try again but every other app works. I tried to reset the date/time, clear cache, clear data, but nothing will work. PLEASE HELP ME its a nextbook tablet by android

Comment: Umm... Some more details please? Android version, device chipset, other hardware details, etc.? Also, have you bothered to check your internet connection or reorienting the device(s) involved so they can get better signals?

Answer (score 1):

it may well be that google play services is out of date. Try logging out of and back into your google account, try restarting the phone, if all else fails, backup your data and do a factory reset.